# Where has the option to mount as hard drive gone ...?

Tags: htc-sense, htc-desire-hd, connection-issues, usb-connection-mode, mount

I have an HTC Desire HD (on Vodafone UK). I noticed this week that when I now connect it to either pc or mac the option to mount as a hard drive is no longer present. Why? What do I need to do to get it back?

Comment: Has anything changed since last time you were able to mount successfully?  E.g. new Android OS version, new apps, new computer, new USB cable?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that I *may* have d/loaded a couple of apps, but nothing that should mess with core Android features in this way. e.g. Solitaire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I had a look at [this thread](http://androidforums.com/desire-support-troubleshooting/89434-cant-mount-desire-disk-drive.html) and, as it suggests, I took the microSD out and put it back in again. Now it works as before. Smells like a bug to me?

Comment: The exact same thing happened to me - taking out the SD card resolved it too.